# MySQL: get all users who haven't done any training in 2 years

Tags: mysql

I need to get all users who haven't carried out any training in the last two years.

We run 3 courses a year: Basic 1 in January, Basic 2 in February and Basic 3 in March.

Not everyone needs to do the training each year but everyone must have completed a course in the last 2 years in order to keep their registration. At present we look through each User record and highlight the user if none of their training courses occurred in the last 2 years but, as the number of Users increases, we need to check all Users at once so I've been looking at queries that might provide the data and display the date of their last training and the name of the course if they haven't completed any training in the last 2 years.

So, for instance, given the two tables here:

```
users_temp:
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | David |
| 2  | John  |
| 3  | Barry |
| 4  | Mary  |
+----+-------+

courses_temp:
+---------+------------+---------+
| user_id | date       | name    |
+---------+------------+---------+
| 1       | 2015-01-01 | Basic 1 |
| 1       | 2015-02-02 | Basic 2 |
| 1       | 2015-03-03 | Basic 3 |
| 2       | 2015-01-01 | Basic 1 |
| 2       | 2014-02-02 | Basic 2 |
| 2       | 2014-03-03 | Basic 3 |
| 3       | 2012-01-01 | Basic 1 |
| 3       | 2012-02-02 | Basic 2 |
| 3       | 2013-03-03 | Basic 3 |
| 4       | 2013-01-01 | Basic 1 |
| 4       | 2012-02-02 | Basic 2 |
| 4       | 2012-03-03 | Basic 3 |
+---------+------------+---------+
```

I can manually check and tell that the last training which David took was in March this year, John last took training in January this year, Barry took training in March 2013 and Mary took training in January 2013 so I need to produce a table like this:

```
+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+
| user_id | Name  | Last Training | Last Course |
+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+
| 3       | Barry | 2013-03-03    | Basic 3     |
| 4       | Mary  | 2013-01-01    | Basic 1     |
+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+
```

My first query went like this:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    max(date)
FROM 
    courses_temp
GROUP BY 
    user_id
HAVING
    max(date) < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

To get these results:

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | max(date)  |
+---------+------------+
| 3       | 2013-03-03 |
| 4       | 2013-01-01 |
+---------+------------+
```

To get the name of the user I added:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    max(date),
    users_temp.name
FROM 
    courses_temp
JOIN
    users_temp
ON
    courses_temp.user_id = users_temp.id
GROUP BY 
    user_id
HAVING
    max(date) < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

To get these results:

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| user_id | max(date)  | name  |
+---------+------------+-------+
| 3       | 2013-03-03 | Barry |
| 4       | 2013-01-01 | Mary  |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

To try and get the name of the last course I used this

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    max(date),
    users_temp.name,
    courses_temp.name
FROM 
    courses_temp
JOIN
    users_temp
ON
    courses_temp.user_id = users_temp.id
GROUP BY 
    user_id
HAVING
    max(date) < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

To get these results:

```
+---------+------------+-------+---------+
| user_id | max(date)  | name  | name    |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+
| 3       | 2013-03-03 | Barry | Basic 1 |
| 4       | 2013-01-01 | Mary  | Basic 1 |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+
```

But that's wrong, it should be:

```
+---------+------------+-------+---------+
| user_id | max(date)  | name  | name    |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+
| 3       | 2013-03-03 | Barry | Basic 1 |
| 4       | 2013-01-01 | Mary  | Basic 3 |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+
```

How do I get the correct course name (**Basic 3**) to come through please?

Comment: i think you have the course names switched in your last table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're over complicating things. The `left join` takes care of finding the most recent training attended - if there is no row in `courses_temp c2` with the same id, and more recent date than the corresponding row in `courses_temp c1`, you will get null values which allow us to identify the most recent row per user. After that, it's gravy.

```
select u.*, c1.name, c1.date
  from users_temp u
    inner join courses_temp c1
      on u.id = c1.user_id
    left join courses_temp c2
      on u.id = c2.user_id and c1.date < c2.date
  where c2.date is null and c1.date < now() - interval 2 year;
```

Your last attempt is a great example of mysqls helpful `group by` processing being a bit of a bugbear. You can't rely on it to pick the correct value for any field not present in the `group by` constraint, or not used in an aggregate formula. See [12.16.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for more details

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause [ ... ] You can
>   use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary
>   column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when
>   all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are
>   the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from
>   each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are
>   indeterminate.